# Consulta com agrupamento

Tags: sql, query, firebird

Bom dia senhores(as)
Estou com o seguinte problema:
[Editado]

Como pode ser visto na imagem acima, há vários campos com os mesmos resultado (menos a coluna "desric"). O que necessito, é que além de agrupar os resultados identicos, a coluna desric ficasse +- assim: "Animais domésticos, ruído";

Algo semelhante a isto:

|DESRIC|MEDPPIC|CONDFEPIC|USOIEPIC|PRZVEPIC|PERTEPIC|HIGEPIC|

|ANIMAIS DOMESTICOS|S|N|S|S|S|S|S|

|ANIMAIS DOMESTICOS, RUÍDO|S|S|S|S|S|S|S|

Desculpe a formatação, mas acredito que dê para entender.

Segue imagem de meu sql [Editado]

----EDIT----

Acabei encontrando o comando LIST(), Que faz exatamente o que eu quero, mas gostaria de saber ainda a partir de qual versão está função foi implementada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondendo sua pergunta de quando o List foi implementado:

- Adicionado na versão 2.1
- Alteado na versão 2.5

Para mais informações você pode ver na [documentação do Firebird](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-aggrfunc-list.html)

Esperto ter ajudado

Comment: Existe alguma função semelhante na versão 1.5? Já pesquisei por tudo e nada encontrei.

Comment: A versão 1.5 do Firebird é praticamente um Interbase recompilado, você pode procurar por algo para Interbase (verificando a versão) e tentar no Firebird.

Comment: Eu não posso deixar de te aconselhar a migrar para a versão mais nova do Firebird. Hoje utilizo  a versão 2.5.2 e estou migrando para 3. Da 1.5 para 3.0 as mudanças são gritantes. Considere essa mudança o quanto antes.

Comment: Em minha máquina (desenvolvimento) utilizamos a versão 2.5.9 do firebird, portanto localmente funcionaria, mas há diversos clientes cada um com dezenas de milhares de registros que ainda utilizam a versão 1.5.

Comment: Nesse caso o melhor é não usar um recurso do >2.5. Tente contornar utilizando uma procedure ou trazer o problema para ser resolvido na aplicação. Infelizmente não vejo muita saída.

Comment: Exatamente. não consegui encontrar nenhum exemplo de sp que possa me auxiliar. E assim de cabeça, não faço a mínima idéia do que fazer.

Comment: Vou repassar o problema pro DBA aqui que é bem curioso no assunto. Se ele tiver alguma ideia eu te reporto.

Comment: Por favor, faça isso. Preciso mesmo de ajuda.

Comment: @Edenilson o Rodrigo que é o DBA aqui fez uma solução e publicou como resposta. Veja se te ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia. Você pode fazer uma procedure para retornar uma lista e coloca-la em sua sql.
Segue o exemplo abaixo:

```
CREATE OR ALTER procedure GET_LISTA (
    SQL_LISTA varchar(1000))
returns (
    LISTA varchar(4000))
as
declare variable ADD_LISTA varchar(100);
begin
  FOR EXECUTE STATEMENT SQL_LISTA INTO :ADD_LISTA DO
  BEGIN
    IF( LISTA IS NOT NULL ) THEN
    BEGIN
        LISTA = LISTA || ',' || ADD_LISTA;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        LISTA = ADD_LISTA;
    END
  END
  suspend;
end

SELECT DISTINCT
A.MEDPPIC,A.CONDFEPIC,A.USOIEPIC,A.PRZVEPIC,A.PERTEPIC,A.HIGEPIC,
(
 SELECT * 
 FROM GET_LISTA('SELECT DISTINCT C.DESCRIC FROM ESAEPIC A INNER JOIN ESACER B ON B.IDEPIC=A.IDEPIC INNER JOIN ESARIC C ON C.CODRIC=B.RICCER 
 WHERE A.MEDPPIC='||A.MEDPPIC||' AND A.CONDFEPIC='||A.CONDFEPIC||' AND A.USOIEPIC='||A.USOIEPIC||' AND A.PRZVEPIC='||A.PRZVEPIC||' AND A.HIGEPIC='||A.HIGEPIC)
) AS DESCRIC
FROM ESAEPIC A
INNER JOIN ESACER B ON B.IDEPIC=A.IDEPIC
INNER JOIN ESARIC C ON C.CODRIC=B.RICCER
WHERE A.IDEPIC IN(SELECT IDEPIC FROM ESACER WHERE CLCCER = :CLCCER)
```

Só não testei a sql pois não tenho a estrutura do banco e os dados, mas na minha base com meus dados deu certo.

Comment: Vou testar aqui e já te respondo.

Comment: Amigo, funcionou para mim aqui mas tive que fazer algumas pequenas adaptações. Agradeço pela ajuda. Amanhã postarei aqui como resposta a versão definitiva, para que se mais pessoas precisarem.

Comment: O ideal mesmo é fazer a migração dos clientes que estão na versão mais antiga pra nova e usar o "list". Mas no pior caso você consegue fazer dessa forma.

Comment: Com certeza o ideal é atualizar, mas o problema é que estes clientes tem base de dados muito grande e qualquer probleminha de incompatibilidade gera uma dor de cabeça fenomenal.